# What is the rule determining use of the definite article in the expressions like "with (the?) speed equal to"?

Tags: articles

What is the rule determining whether one must use the (definite) article in the expressions like:

> 1. the ball of (the) radius 1
> 2. a drop with (the) charge 2q

I meet quite often both variants, but see no pattern:

> 3. [...] moves with the speed equal to the velocity of water
> 4. The train would reach its destination with speed equal to zero
> 5. Kant's point, therefore, is that instantaneous states of motion (whether with speed equal to zero or any other value) [...]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two rules I found:

> 1. The word "the" is one of the most common words in English. It is our only definite article. Nouns in English are preceded by the definite article when the speaker believes that the listener already knows what he is referring to. The speaker may believe this for many different reasons, some of which are listed below. [[1.]](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/definite-article/)
> 2. *The* is called a definite article. "Definite" means "specific". Use *the* when talking about something which is already known to the listener or which has been previously mentioned, introduced, or discussed. [[2.]](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm)

I will number your examples:

1. the ball of (the) radius 1
2. a drop with (the) charge 2q
3. [...] moves with the speed equal to the velocity of water
4. The train would reach its destination with speed equal to zero.
5. Kant's point, therefore, is that instantaneous states of motion (whether with speed equal to zero or any other value) [...]

For 1., *the ball* is ok because I suppose that this ball was introduced earlier in the text. I study math, so to me it comes off as some kind of exercise in math or physics. I can imagine that the paragraph begins something like

> Suppose a ball is thrown in the air. The ball of radius 1 travels at a rate of ...

Notice that I omit *the* from (the radius) because the radius was not previously provided. In other words, you cannot use the word *the* to refer to a radius because a radius was not previously defined.

For 2., again, the charge was not previously defined. So you cannot refer it it. Therefore, you omit *the* and write

> A drop with charge 2q.

For 3., "with the speed of" sounds strange because you have not defined or provided which speed. You are about to define it as "equal to the velocity of water". I assume that you understand or previously defined what the "velocity of water" is. Because you already know what "velocity of water" is, you can use the word *the*.

For 4., I assume that this "train" was introduced earlier in the conversation or text, therefore it is understood what *the* means. Like maybe it was a blue train, or a local train, or a big train, etc.

For 5., seems fine. No need for *the*.

Also note, there might be some exceptions to these rules. But I could not think of any at the moment.

Comment: In terms of #4, I think the OP's question revolves around the phrase **"with speed equal to"**. Can we say **with a speed of 2Km/h**... or **with the speed of sound**?

Comment: I see your point. Do not delete your comment. I will let OP ask if he/she needs clarification on number 4.

Comment: I think your logic is clear: you will probably say that no article is needed.

Comment: @Serguei Yes, in the case "with speed equal to", no article is need because you have not introduced _which_ speed. You are about to do that. In the case of "with the speed of sound", I believe there is only **one** speed of sound, so it is clear to what the word _the_ refers.

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you mean, I normally must write "with speed equal to 300m/s", but  "with _the_ speed of sound"?

Comment: @Serguei Yes, normally. I can imagine cases where you could write "with _the_ speed" but I do not want to confuse you. I will try to give you some examples, if you request them.

Comment: What really confuses me is the feeling that the words "speed", "charge", etc. have something special in them. I suspect you would say: "I walked in the garden and met a  girl with  **a** flower" . Or will it be "a  girl with flower"? What makes flower so different from, say, diameter?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would say "a flower". Ok, I had to think about it, and I think I figured it out. Sometimes, the **speed** or **charge** of something is ***implied***. For example, let's say you have a device and you are reading the instructions. This device has a rotating mechanism and it has 3 speeds, speed 1 is low, 2 is medium, 3 is high. Let's the that for purpose X, the instructions say "Turn on the device and set _the_ speed to 1". See, because the device is on, it is implied that the speed we are talking about is the speed of the rotating mechanism.

Comment: Definite does not mean specific. Definiteness and specificity are two different qualities of a noun phrase. A noun phrase can be specific but not definite: *I married a guy from Canada*. This refers to a specific guy. People get these terms mixed up probably because most of the time that something is *definite* it is also specific. But the reverse is not true.